# Removing backslash from directories & files with Python

Tags: python, regex, path

I have code similar to:

```
chars = ['~', '*', '\\', ':', '<', '>', '|', '?', '"']

def ReplaceChars(value):
    for c in chars:
        value = value.replace(c, '')
    return value


def RenamePath(root, path):
    newFilePath = ReplaceChars(path)
    os.rename(os.path.join(root, path), os.path.join(root, newFilePath))


def WalkFileSystem(dirroot):
    # Main Walk Through File System
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirroot, topdown=False):

    for name in dirs:
        searchObj = re.search(r'[%s]' % ''.join(chars), name)
        if searchObj:
            RenamePath(root, name)

    for name in files:
        searchObj = re.search(r'[%s]' % ''.join(chars), name)
        if searchObj:
            RenamePath(root, name)
```

The issue is if a directory or file contains a backslash it won't remove it. By removing the `r` I no longer read it as a raw string and instead use four backslashes, two is needed by the regex pattern. The regex pattern appears in the first arg as I expect and the search picks it up. It just won't remove the backslash from the path string and I don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: you can `re.escape` any string to match it literally.

Comment: _"By Removing the r I no longer read it as a rawstring"_. I don't think raw strings do anything here. `r"[%s]"` and `"[%s]"` are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw string doesn't do anything useful in the `r'[%s]' % ''.join(chars)` interpolation, it first gets evaluated, doesn't escape anything, and then the `chars` is joined and substituted. So it's the same as doing `'[%s]' % ''.join(chars)`.

The problem with `\`s here is that you need `'\\\\'` (or `r'\\'`) for regex and `'\\'` for replacement. Regex needs one more level of escape, so you cannot use the same string for both:

```
>>> path = 'a\\path'
>>> re.search('[\\\\]', path)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10d5c6920>
>>> path = 'a\\path'
>>> path.replace('\\\\', '')
'a\\path'
>>> path.replace('\\', '')
'apath'
```

You can either use separate `chars` arrays for searching and replacing:

```
chars_search = ['~', '*', '\\\\', ':', '<', '>', '|', '?', '"']
chars_replace = ['~', '*', '\\', ':', '<', '>', '|', '?', '"']
```

or have it all in one:

```
chars = ['~', '*', '\\\\', '\\', ':', '<', '>', '|', '?', '"']
```

What suits you best.

Comment: Thanks garkin. Perfect answer. The regex side was fine but of course it was not going to work on the replace.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: `'[%s]' % ''.join(chars).encode('string_escape')`**

You can either use this solution or the one provided by famousgarkin. Whichever suits your needs

---

So, after much investigation and testing, I have found that your raw string command

`r'[%s]' % ''.join(chars)`

doesn't do what you want it to. You can test this in a Python console by running this:

Commands: `r'[%s]' % ''.join(chars)` vs. `r'[~*\\:<>|?"]'`

Output: `'[~*\\:<>|?"]'` vs. `'[~*\\\\:<>|?"]'`.

Hope this works for you.

**Explanation to why raw string didn't work**

Here are the different inputs/outputs for the following two commands:

Inputs: `r''.join(chars)` vs. `r'\\'.join(chars)`

Outputs: `~*\\:<>|?"` vs. `~\\\\*\\\\\\\\\\:\\\\<\\\\>\\\\|\\\\?\\\\"`

What I'm trying to prove with these outputs is that the raw string notation only applied on the string directly attached to it, and not on anything else afterwards. So basically, the raw string interpreted `r''` as `''` and `r'\\'` as `'\\\\'`. It then applies everything else. If you look at the second output, you will see that after the asterisk, there are the four backslashes (as should be), but then, there are 6 backslashes in total. This means the `\\` from the `chars` list was read in without raw string conversion, followed by the join's four backslashes.

Again, hope this helps.

---